# AnsibleTower sending every n-th notification

Tags: rhel, smtp, ansible-tower

I have automated some stuff using AnsibleTower (4.1.1, RHEL8 4.18.0-372.19) and it works as expected. Yet when it comes to sending email notifications, there is something I cannot explain. The Tower is sending every n-th email, despite saying in the /var/log/tower/tower.log that 'notification has been sent'. I have checked its behaviour using tcpdump (tcpdump -i interface dst host smtp_server_here --vv ) and yes in fact I can see that it tries to contact the server on every second or third notification.
Firewalld is on (no 'limit notifications' richRules present) so is Selinux.
What should I check?

rgrds,
noob

Comment: in /var/log/tower/task_system.log I found entries sayinf "Failed to even try to send notifications for job.... due to job not being in finished state".

Answer (score 0):

Check in the /var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib/python3.8/site-packages/awx/main/tasks.py

Look for the stanza starting with:
{{@task(queue=get_local_queuename)
def handle_success_and_failure_notifications(job_id):}}

There will be a parameter starting with 'retry if failed'. By default, it is set to 5. Change this number to something higher (128 worked for me) and restart the service.